# Alignment of the titles in a ToC and \Roman{section}

Tags: sectioning, table-of-contents, horizontal-alignment

There is a problem with the alignment of the numbering of the ToC:
When we use

```
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\Roman{section}}
```

the numbers encroach on the titles.
When the command is commented out, the numbers are all aligned [from the first number on the left] but the titles do not begin at the same position.

What I want is to use `\Roman{section}` but with the numbers being displaced after V (or 9 in arabic) so that the first letters of the  titles are all aligned !

An illustration:

```
%\RequirePackage{fix-cm}
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt, twoside]{article}

\renewcommand{\thesection}{\Roman{section}}

\begin{document}


\tableofcontents
\normalfont
%\cleardoublepage

\section{QWERTY}
\section{QWERTY}
\section{QWERTY}
\section{QWERTY}
\section{QWERTY}
\section{QWERTY}
\section{QWERTY}
\section{QWERTY}
\section{QWERTY}
\section{QWERTY}
\section{QWERTY}
\section{QWERTY}
\section{QWERTY}
\section{QWERTY}
\section{QWERTY}
\section{QWERTY}
\section{QWERTY}
\section{QWERTY}
\section{QWERTY}
\section{QWERTY}
\section{QWERTY}
\section{QWERTY}
\section{QWERTY}
\section{QWERTY}
\section{QWERTY}
\section{QWERTY}
\section{QWERTY}
\section{QWERTY}
\section{QWERTY}
\section{QWERTY}
\section{QWERTY}
\section{QWERTY}
\section{QWERTY}
\section{QWERTY}
\section{QWERTY}
\section{QWERTY}
\section{QWERTY}
\section{QWERTY}
\section{QWERTY}
\section{QWERTY}
\section{QWERTY}
\section{QWERTY}
\section{QWERTY}
\section{QWERTY}
\section{QWERTY}
\section{QWERTY}
\section{QWERTY}
\section{QWERTY}
\section{QWERTY}
\section{QWERTY}
\section{QWERTY}
\section{QWERTY}
\section{QWERTY}
\section{QWERTY}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

The length `\@tempdima` in `\l@section` is responsible for the width of the sectional titles. By default it's set to `1.5em` (taken from [`article.cls`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/unpacked/article.cls)):

```
\newcommand*\l@section[2]{%
  \ifnum \c@tocdepth >\z@
    \addpenalty\@secpenalty
    \addvspace{1.0em \@plus\p@}%
    \setlength\@tempdima{1.5em}%
    \begingroup
      \parindent \z@ \rightskip \@pnumwidth
      \parfillskip -\@pnumwidth
      \leavevmode \bfseries
      \advance\leftskip\@tempdima
      \hskip -\leftskip
      #1\nobreak\hfil \nobreak\hb@xt@\@pnumwidth{\hss #2}\par
    \endgroup
  \fi}
```

How is this possible? Well, the actual display of the sectional number in the ToC is set via `\numberline`, which looks like (from [`latex.ltx`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/unpacked/latex.ltx)):

```
\def\numberline#1{\hb@xt@\@tempdima{#1\hfil}}
```

So, `\numberline{<stuff>}` sets its contents in a box of width `\@tempdima`, left-aligned (as a result of the ending `\hfil`).

You can change the length of `\@tempdima` to your liking via a patch from [`etoolbox`](http://ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox) (in your preamble):

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}% http://ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\l@section}{1.5em}{6em}{}{}% <cmd><search><replace><success><failure>
\makeatother
```

[image]

A similar (easier) result is possible via [`tocloft`](http://ctan.org/pkg/tocloft):

```
\usepackage{tocloft}% http://ctan.org/pkg/tocloft
\setlength\cftsecnumwidth{6em}
```

Comment: in case there is a follow-up with subsections not being now aligned: `\makeatletter\def\l@subsection{\@dottedtocline{2}{6em}{1.5em}}\makeatother` where I have here also replaced `1.5em` by  `6em` and assumed that `\thesubsection` does not use the section Roman number.