# Contents section number and name clashing. Want to increase spacing

Tags: spacing, table-of-contents

I am using Roman Numerals for the contents page however this is clashing with the section title as shown in the image. Is it possible to increase the spacing between these two? 
Many thanks in advance.

[image: The section number and title are clashing]

Comment: possible duplicate: [Alignment of the titles in a ToC and \Roman{section}](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/139814/579).

Comment: p.s. Welcome to TeX.SX!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In short, add this to your preamble to change the dimension you need.

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% Change VVV to alter spacing
\patchcmd{\l@section}{\@tempdima{1.5em}}{\@tempdima{3.5em}}{}{}
\makeatother
```